# Обход ограничения по частоте обращений к VK API

Tags: вконтакте, api, token

Привет! Вычитал, что обходя ограничение по количеству обращений к VK API, можно использовать несколько токенов и подставлять их рандомно в запросы.

Интересует, должны ли эти токены относиться к разным аккаунтам или могут быть привязаны к одному?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать как токены от одного аккаунта для разных приложений, так и  токены от разных аккаунтов для одного приложения.

Но лучше всего использовать метод [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute). Он позволяет выполнять до 25 запросов, в один запрос, написанный на внутреннем языке (что-то похожее на урезанный js). запросы внутри метода выполняются в разы быстрее, что позволяет не только увеличить ограничение в ~25 раз, но и сократить время выполнения запросов.

Comment: Внутри code может содержаться не более 25 обращений к методам API.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Либо изменили недавно, либо я запамятовал)

Comment: Спасибо! Как раз пытаюсь наладить работу с `execute`, где даже при его использовании на частых поисках, говорят, в разных токенах может иметься необходимость.